# Add and delete rows and columns in a table dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables, visualforce

I need to add a row and column as well as delete a row and column in a table dynamically using jquery.Can anyone help me out..

Till now i am trying to display the table and configurable which means draggable and resizable...

below is my code

```
</apex:page>
<apex:page Controller="PositionDataTableController" standardStylesheets="false" readOnly="true" showHeader="false" >
<head>
    <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
    <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/u/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"/>
    <apex:includescript value="//legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/ColReorderWithResize.js"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/u/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.css" />

   <style>
        tr.group,
        tr.group:hover {
        background-color: #ddd !important;
                    }
    </style>
    <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#positiontable').dataTable( {
         "sDom": "Rlfrtip"            
  } );

 } );

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="positiontable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Name</th>
                <th align="left">Cost</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!book}" var="bk">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!bk.Name}</td>
                    <td>{!bk.Cost__c}</td>                        
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Provide more information.. What have you tried so far??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Answer (score 0):

use

```
table.fnAddRow(['Sfdc','learner']);
```

to add row in table

and to remove row from datatable

```
table.fnDeleteRow(row);
```

table is datatable object.
row is datatable row object which you want to delete

also see [this](https://datatables.net/blog/2012-05-31)